# Compare a batch file loop variable in an If statement

Tags: loops, batch-file

I have the following batch file (saved in a file):

```
@echo off
for /r %%F in (*.png) do (
  echo   "%%~nF%%~xF" %%~zF  
)
```

I run this and it will print out this result:

```
  "MyFile1.png" 16330  
  "MyFile2.png" 26042  
  "MyFile3.png" 43346  
  "MyFile4.png" 47862  
  "MyFile5.png" 318131
```

I want to change this to filter out all the large files (the number is the size in bytes).  So as a test I tried this:

```
@echo off
for /r %%F in (*.png) do (
  echo   "%%~nF%%~xF" %%~zF  
  if %%~zF gtr 100000
      Echo Is BIG
)
```

Thinking it would print "Is Big" after the last item in the list.

But Instead I got:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Is it possible to compare with an `If` statement to a loop variable?

Or is there some other way to get all files over a specific size?

In the end, I am looking for something like this:

```
@echo off
for /r %%F in (*.png) do (
  if %%~zF gtr 100000
      Resize %%F by .5  
)
```

(NOTE: The Resize line is pseudo, I don't have that part created yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /r %%F in (*.png) do (
  echo   "%%~nF%%~xF" %%~zF  
  if %%~zF gtr 100000 (
      Echo Is BIG
  )
)
```

or

```
@echo off
for /r %%F in (*.png) do (
  echo   "%%~nF%%~xF" %%~zF  
  if %%~zF gtr 100000 Echo Is BIG
)
```

the next line in batch is other command so without brackets or without a command IF is incomplete.